# django problem to compare database entries with an if statement

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have the following code in my emp/views.py:

```
@ login_required
def peoples(request):

    list_a = []
    if request.user.username == People.objects.get(account=request.user.username):
            angestellte_list = People.objects.all()
            return render_to_response(("emp/people.html"), {'list_a': list_a})
    else:
            return HttpResponse("Nope, it doesn't works")
```

I always get the printout of the else statement. But why?

If I use a explicit example in the if statement it works, e.g.

```
if request.user.username == 'bob':
....
....
```

I don't understand it.

edit:

```
class People(models.Model): 
    empid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=0, primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True) 
    SHIFT_CHOICES=( ('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C'), ('D', 'D'), ('N', 'N'),) 
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIFT_CHOICES, blank=True) 
    account = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True) 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.lastname 
    class Meta: 
        db_table = u'people'
```

2nd edit:

Sorry for the late answering, but i hadn't much time for coding the last days. I found the problem. People.objects.get(account=request.user.username) takes the name but it deletes the first character and capitalizes the second one and only request.user.username takes the exact name. 
An example:

request.user.username = pstefan

Employee.objects.get(account=request.user.username) = Stefan

I solved it this way:

```
username  = str(request.user.username)[1:]
compare   = str(People.objects.get(account=request.user.username))
user_end  = username.replace(username[0], compare[0], 1)
if user_end == compare:
....
```

It works, but i know it isn't the best way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you write your __People__model structure? It might be something about that...

Comment: First, edit your question make additions... 

How did you set __account__ information of an employee record?

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing a username (CharField) to an Person object. Try :

```
if request.user == People.objects.get(...).account:
```

or better still you could use:

```
import django.shortcuts as shortcuts
shortcuts.get_object_or_404(People, account=request.username)
```

Comment: With the first method? have you tried debugging request.user?

Comment: Yes with both methods. How can i debug request.user?

Comment: Often we use `print repr(request.user), repr(People.objects.get(account=request.user.username)` or whatever objects you're trying to compare.  Sometimes, we modify the template to include lots of extra debugging details like this.

Comment: I think i know what the problem is. If i use return         repr(request.user.username) in my else statement i get my current user back but if i use return repr(People.objects.get(account=request.user.username), i get anything back. I think that's the problem but how can i solve it.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by i get anything? if no object was returned it should return DoesNotExist?

Comment: The only thing what returns, is a white page.

Comment: @The_Fox: Don't use `return repr(request.user.username)`.  Print it.  With `print`.  So that it goes to the log. "a white page" doesn't mean anything.  (1) View Source in your browser.  (2) Fix Your Templates to Show Something.

Comment: based on your last edit - in your model account should be a ForeignKey to the user model, which is what request.user returns

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine what the "account" attribute is on the Peoples object and how it relates to user. If you can post the Peoples model, it may be easier to determine the solution.